# Azure AD How to get the Tenant Id from the user when he authenticated to our application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I've created an Asp.net application with Azure Active Directory authentication by using OAuth2 and working as expected.

Now when the user login to my application, I'm getting the user data like **User Email id and provider key**

Now the requirement is, I need to get user tenant Id from the response.

Is there any chance to get the user tenant id from the response?

Here I'm using GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() to get the authenticated user data.

```
  private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }
   var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please share the code. Usually tenant id should be available in the result object.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, since I've shared my code snippet.
 can you please look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now the requirement is, I need to get user tenant Id from the response.

`loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider` would look like as follows:

```
https://sts.windows.net/{tenant-Id}/
```

Or you could retrieve the tenant Id via the following code snippet:

```
var tenantId = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
```

and make sure that your application should have the following permissions:
1) Read directory data
2) Read all users full profiles
3) Sign in and read user profile